# Is it a good practice to separate lower level code from ReactiveX

Tags: design-patterns, reactive

Consider I have a `Calculator` class, it calculates an `Integer`. On higher parts of the system, say a MVP presenter, I want to work with an ReactiveX Observable that emits the `Integer`.

I could do the following:

```
public class Calculator {

    public Observable<Integer> doSomeVeryComplicatedCalculations() {

        return Observable.just(0);

    }

}
```

I am wondering if it is a good practice to keep the `Calculator` class free from ReactiveX and use a wrapper like this:

```
public class Calculator {

    public Integer doSomeVeryComplicatedCalculations() {

        return 0;

    }

}


public class RxCalculator {

    public Observable<Integer> doSomeVeryComplicatedCalculations() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext(new Calculator().doSomeVeryComplicatedCalculations());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This way the actual `Calculator`

**a.** can be tested without ReactiveX where imho ReactiveX adds some complexity to testing

**b.** the `Calculator` class can be used in projects that don't use ReactiveX.

Are there any downsides to this, besides of course that I'll end up with more code / classes?

Comment: This certainly *seems* like a textbook example of good coding practices to me, but I don't do much Java and I've never used ReactiveX so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is a good practice to keep the Calculator class
>   free from ReactiveX and use a wrapper

Yes. You should not depend on your framework, library or tool. Depend on abstractions, not on implementations.

I am PHP programmer and once I was looking for a good http library to use in my project. I chose [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). It's really good. It has tons of features from which I use only 1% ;) I used it in several projects of mine through all the code.

But the next version of Guzzle was released with backwards incompatible changes. They changed a lot (for the better). And I suddenly realized, that I depend on previous Guzzle version through all my code! To switch to a newer version means, that I need to rewrite a good bunch of it.

Now when I'm using some powerful external library, I always create a wrapper, that has only features enough to suit my needs and allows me to quickly swap implementation.

Comment: Vladislav is right, never let your business objects be enslaved by any tools.